# How can i upoad file in Playwright-java?

Tags: playwright

How can i upload file in Playwright-java?
Using playwright-java, how can one upload files from system to web application on uploadFile webelement

Answer (score 2):

```
page.setInputFiles("xpath or CSS of upload button",Path.of("path to your file"));
```